# How to make git gui not show untracked files

Tags: git, git-gui

I have a lot of untracked files in my project. I would like to be able to tell git gui not to show them when showing the list of candidate-for-staging files. Is there a way to do that?

Similarly, it would be nice to be able to see only files in a certain .

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are these things that you don't want to track, like generated files/binary blobs?

Answer (score 3):

Just to make sure: in my case (maybe a rather old version of Git Gui: 0.20) the setting can be found using the following navigation:

> Git Gui => Edit => Options

Now in the "Options" dialog there's a CheckBox in the lower-left area labeled #Show untracked files#.

De-selecting this option did the trick!

EDIT:
The referenced CheckBox in the lower-left area is for the current branch - there's another one on the right side of this screen, which controls the handling on a global level (i.e. for all Git repository on your computer).

Answer (score 2):

Go to

> Git Gui > Preferences

It has an option

> Show untracked files

and uncheck it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file and add the files you don't want shown - most, if not all UIs for git should respect it.

Comment: Gitignore will not help - there is no easy filename pattern that I could use, and the list changes quite frequently. I am looking for something like the -uno switch of git status

Comment: It sounds like you need to clean up your workspace a bit - how are all of these files making it into your workspace?  Are they all under a single folder?  Can you use wildcards to ignore them?  I'm not sure what kind of solution you're looking for where gitignore doesn't work, but something for a git gui does.